# UITableView and popover : dismiss popover and select row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, popover

I have a little problem. I have a table view and when the user select a row, a popover is display with it contents. But if I want to select another row in the table view I need to tap once for dismiss the popover and another time for select the row.

How can I do the same thing but only with one tap : dismiss and select the row ?

Chears,
iBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Dismiss the popover in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of the popover's table view.</strike>

When creating the popover or pushing the segue in the table view controller:

```
popoverController.passthroughViews = @[self.tableView];
```

Comment: I can't because the popover is created when a row is selected

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath method will call on second tap. So he cant do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the property passthroughViews on the UIPopoverViewController [UIPopoverController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you add your tableview to this array, you'll be able to receive the didSelectRow call